# How do I recursively search an object tree and return the matching object based on a key/value using JavaScript/Prototype 1.7

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, prototype, javascript-objects

I've got some nested object data and I want to search it and return the matching object based on the id.

```
var data = [{id: 0, name: 'Template 0', subComponents:[
        {id: 1, name: 'Template 1', subItems:[
            {id: 2, name: 'Template 2', subComponents:[{id: 3, name: 'Template 3'}], subItems: [{id: 4, name: 'Template 4'}]}
        ]}
    ]}
];
```

So I want to do something like this

```
getObjectByKeyValue({id: 3})
```

and have it return

```
{id: 3, name: 'Template 3'}
```

It's sort of got to be done generically because I have subItems, AND subComponents which could each have children.

I tried this using Prototype 1.7 and no luck - I think this just searches an array, and not a tree with it's sub nodes:

```
data.find(function(s){return s.id == 4;})
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I went a slightly different route and made the `findKey` method an Object protype:

```
Object.prototype.findKey = function(keyObj) {
    var p, key, val, tRet;
    for (p in keyObj) {
        if (keyObj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            key = p;
            val = keyObj[p];
        }
    }

    for (p in this) {
        if (p == key) {
            if (this[p] == val) {
                return this;
            }
        } else if (this[p] instanceof Object) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                tRet = this[p].findKey(keyObj);
                if (tRet) { return tRet; }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

Which you would call directly on the data object, passing in the key/value you're looking for:

```
data.findKey({ id: 3 });
```

Note that this function allows you to find an object based on any key:

```
data.findKey({ name: 'Template 0' });
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/3QYDp/) (open console to view result)

Comment: I like this solution a lot better but this doesn't seem to work when the prototype library is in the mix - any clue how to make it work with the prototype library?

Comment: I switched the fiddle to include the Prototype 1.7 library and it still works for me so I'm not sure what issue you're having.

Comment: Nice solution. What if I want to search based on multiple keys. Added a [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742659/search-within-multilevel-json-tree-using-multiple-keys) for the same

Comment: Bad bad bad! Extension of the native object prototype!

Comment: If you don't want to extend the object prototype this is easily modifiable to be a standalone method-- just pass in the data to search and replace references to this with the passed argument name.

Answer (score 5):

Not the best of the and final solution.
But can get you a start for what you are looking...

```
var data = [{id: 0, name: 'Template 0', subComponents:[
        {id: 1, name: 'Template 1', subItems:[
            {id: 2, name: 'Template 2', subComponents:[{id: 3, name: 'Template 3'}], subItems: [{id: 4, name: 'Template 4'}]}
        ]}
    ]}
];


function returnObject(data,key,parent){
    for(var v in data){

        var d = data[v];
        if(d==key){
            return parent[0];
        }
        if(d instanceof Object){
            return returnObject(d,key,data);
        };

    }
}

function returnObjectWrapper(datavar,key){
    return returnObject(datavar,key.id)
}

returnObjectWrapper(data,{id:3})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my solution below or http://jsfiddle.net/8Y6zq/:

```
var findByKey = function (obj, key) {
var j, key = key || '', obj = obj || {}, keys = key.split("."), 
    sObj = [], ssObj = [], isSelector = !!(keys.length > 0);

    var findKey = function (obj, key) {
        var k;
        for (k in obj) {
            if (k === key) {
                sObj.push(obj[k]);
            } else if (typeof obj[k] == 'object') {
                findKey(obj[k], key);
            }
        }
    };

    if (isSelector) {
        var nKey = keys.shift();
        findKey(obj, nKey);

        while (keys.length > 0) {
            nKey = keys.shift();

            if (sObj.length > 0) {
                ssObj = sObj.slice(0), sObj = [];
                for (j in ssObj) {
                    findKey(ssObj[j], nKey);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        findKey(obj, key);
    }

    // return occurrences of key in array
    return (sObj.length === 1) ? sObj.pop() : sObj;
};

var data = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Template 0', subComponents: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Template 1', subItems: [
            {id: 2, name: 'Template 2', subComponents: [
                {id: 3, name: 'Template 3'}
            ], subItems: [
                {id: 4, name: 'Template 4'}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]},
    {subComponents:{
        comp1:'comp1 value',
        comp2:'comp2 value',
    }}
];

alert(JSON.stringify(findByKey(data, 'subComponents')));
alert(JSON.stringify(findByKey(data, 'subComponents.comp1')));
alert(JSON.stringify(findByKey(data, 'subComponents.comp2')));
```

In this implementation we can use search by KEY or SELECTOR (eg. `"<paren_key>.<child_key_1>.<child_key_2>. ... <child_key_N>"`)

Answer (score 0):

In case you really need a search through your tree data return all results (not a unique key), here is a little modified version of mVChr's answer:

```
Object.prototype.findKey = function (keyObj) {
var p, key, val, tRet;
var arr = [];

for (p in keyObj) {
    if (keyObj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        key = p;
        val = keyObj[p];
    }
}

for (p in this) {
    if (p == key) {
        if (this[p] == val) {
            arr.push(this);
        }
    } else if (this[p] instanceof Object) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            tRet = this[p].findKey(keyObj);
            if (tRet) {
                for (var i = 0; i < tRet.length; i++)
                    arr.push(tRet[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (arr.length > 0)
    return arr;
else
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We now use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for data processing tasks like this. It's pretty powerful once you wrap your head around how to use it. Here is how you'd answer your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (id, input) => objectScan(['**'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'value',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value.id === id
})(input);

const data = [{ id: 0, name: 'Template 0', subComponents: [{ id: 1, name: 'Template 1', subItems: [{ id: 2, name: 'Template 2', subComponents: [{ id: 3, name: 'Template 3' }], subItems: [{ id: 4, name: 'Template 4' }] }] }] }];

console.log(find(3, data));
// => { id: 3, name: 'Template 3' }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)