# Search within multilevel json tree using multiple keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tree

I have a json tree with following structure

```
{
    "treeId": "avhsgdkendkfhjsdoiendsj",
    "groupResponse": {
        "description": null,
        "id": "avhsgdkendkfhjsdoiendsj",
        "mAttr": null,
        "mAttrVal": null
    },
    "childResponse": [
    {
        "treeId": "6p263uh38xvnchmsrw2jn48ut",
        "childResponse": [],
        "groupResponse": {
            "description":null,
            "id ":"6p263uh38xvnchmsrw2jn48ut",
            "mAttr": "xxx",
            "mAttrVal": "222"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "treeId": "2fywxwi93lg7fqggdqqpqxvpg",
        "childResponse": [],
        "groupResponse": {
            "description ":null,
            "id": "2fywxwi93lg7fqggdqqpqxvpg",
            "mAttr": "xxx",
            "mAttrVal": "111"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to search for a node based on single/multiple key(s) e.g. `{ "mAttr": "xxx",  "mAttrVal","222"}`

I found a solution mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5447398/456135)

```
Object.prototype.findKey = function(keyObj) {
    var p, key, val, tRet;
    for (p in keyObj) {
        if (keyObj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            key = p;
            val = keyObj[p];
        }
    }

    for (p in this) {
        if (p == key) {
            if (this[p] == val) {
                return this;
            }
        } else if (this[p] instanceof Object) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                tRet = this[p].findKey(keyObj);
                if (tRet) { return tRet; }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

It can search based on any single key. How to modify it to work with multiple keys? There is no limit to the depth of my tree.

Comment: you want only the first object or every objects with those keys/values ?

Comment: @JuniusRendel I want all such nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might help,

```
var data = {
  'treeId': 'avhsgdkendkfhjsdoiendsj',
  'groupResponse': {
    'description': null,
    'id': 'avhsgdkendkfhjsdoiendsj',
    'mAttr': null,
    'mAttrVal': null
  },
  'childResponse': [
    {
      'treeId': '6p263uh38xvnchmsrw2jn48ut',
      'childResponse': [
      ],
      'groupResponse': {
        'description': null,
        'id ': '6p263uh38xvnchmsrw2jn48ut',
        'mAttr': 'xxx',
        'mAttrVal': '222'
      }
    },
    {
      'treeId': '2fywxwi93lg7fqggdqqpqxvpg',
      'childResponse': [
      ],
      'groupResponse': {
        'description ': null,
        'id': '2fywxwi93lg7fqggdqqpqxvpg',
        'mAttr': 'xxx',
        'mAttrVal': '111'
      }
    }
  ]
};

var search = function(data, qObj){
  var i, k, matched = true, set = [];
  for (k in qObj) {
    if(!qObj.hasOwnProperty(k))
      continue;
    if(!data.groupResponse.hasOwnProperty(k) || data.groupResponse[k] != qObj[k]){
      matched = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(matched){
    set.push(data.groupResponse);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < data.childResponse.length; i++){
    s = search(data.childResponse[i], qObj);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(set, s);
  }
  return set;
}

console.log(search(data, { "mAttr": "xxx", "mAttrVal": "222"}));
```

Output:

```
[{"description":null,"id ":"6p263uh38xvnchmsrw2jn48ut","mAttr":"xxx","mAttrVal":"222"}]
```

hope this helps

Comment: It works for above keys. However when I do `search(data, { "id":"6p263uh38xvnchmsrw2jn48ut"})` it returns no nodes, searching for `search(data, { "id": "2fywxwi93lg7fqggdqqpqxvpg"})` returns correctly though.

Comment: the first childResponse has property name `id `  instead of `id`. Notice an additional `space`. almost had my hair pulled out :)

Comment: HaHa nice catch. Tnx for the help

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but I think it should work

```
Object.prototype.findKey = function(keyObj) {
    var p,key,tRet=[],add=true;
    for (p in this) {
        if (this[p] instanceof Object) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                tRet.concat(this[p].findKey(keyObj));
            }
        }
    }
    for(key in keyObj){
        if(!this.hasOwnProperty(key)||!this[key]===keyObj[key])
            add=false;
    }
    if(add)
        tRet.push(this);
    return tRet;
};
```

Tell me if I'm wrong ;)