# Converting entire window object to string

Tags: javascript

I need to examine the entire window object, in order to check where data is actually being saved.

If i execute `window.toString()` i get `"[object Window]"`
I have also tried with the `JSON.stringify(window)` function and got the following error:

```
VM18766:1 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Is there any way i can get the entire javascript object content including prototype functions?

I need this in order so that i can search inside the object text for specific content being saved in an object and where this object is.

Answer (score 3):

if you try to do `JSON.stringify(window)`, you will get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

From this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) StackOverflow post, you can do the following:

```js
const p = document.getElementById('p');

const getCircularReplacer = () => {
    const seen = new WeakSet();
    return (key, value) => {
        if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
            if (seen.has(value)) {
                return;
            }
            seen.add(value);
        }
        return value;
    };
};

p.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(window, getCircularReplacer());
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p"></p>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `try...catch` block and `JSON.stringify` to filter out the properties that can't be properly converted to JSON. This will capture valid objects, arrays, strings, and numbers. It will exclude functions so if you want those you'll need convert them to strings separately. For example:

```js
function stringifyWindow() {
    let result = {}
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).forEach(key => {
        const value = window[key];
        switch (typeof window[key]) {
           case 'undefined':
               result[key] = 'undefined';
               break;
           case 'function': 
               result[key] = value.toString();
               break;
           default:
               try {
                   result[key] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
               } catch {}
               break;
        }
    });
    return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is impossible to serialize in JSON because, as the error says, it contains circular references. A simple example of this is where every element has a `.children` array and each child has a `.parent` value. This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489119/jquery-javascript-search-dom-for-text-and-insert-html) which might help with what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: i do not want to convert it to json. i just want to see all the objects to see where my data is

Comment: i have a site that is built with knockoutJS. and i want to get the data objects with the content

Comment: @AryehArmon, can you please provide details of exactly what you are trying to extract and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd party library like [this](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json) and see if it outputs what you want. Usage:

```
<script src="circular-json.js"></script>
```

And (e.g. in your onload function)

```
var CircularJSON = window.CircularJSON;
var obj = window;
var str;

obj.self = obj;
console.log(CircularJSON.stringify(obj));
```

You could also just use

```
console.log(window);
```

to inspect the object and search through the object in the browser console.

Comment: i am getting an error: VM10998:2 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)

Comment: To track that I would need to see your entire page. But it seems that you have somewhere iFrames and access to the iFrame is blocked (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame))

Comment: is there a way to search the entire window object for a specific property

Comment: [Maybe that helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443436/how-do-i-recursively-search-an-object-tree-and-return-the-matching-object-based)

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible since the window object is a circular object

For example the object passed in the request has a circular reference, something like:

```
var a = {};
a.b = a;
```